# How to add file to root in multisite installation?

Tags: multi-sites

I have a multisite setup.

```
public html
 - Sites 
 - - All
 - - site1.com
 - - site2.com
etc.
```

I need to .txt files to the root of each website such as site1.com/ads.txt or site2.com/robots.txt

If I upload to public_html the .txt file will be accessible on all sites on the installation. If I install in the individual files folder the .txt file is shown as site1.com/sites/site1.com/files/filename.txt.

How can I show the .txt file at the root of site1.com but not site2.com?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/robotstxt creates dynamic robots.txt per instance. You then may want to copy their approach in a custom module to do the same for ads.txt. Or you simply provide your own route `/ads.txt` with its own controller to serve the content dynamically from a custom module.

Answer (score 0):

I have multisite installation and there are multiple common code or files I am able to access in each site.

- You can add your common php, txt or html etc files in the rootsite folder(or you can make assets directory and specify the path "/assets/ads.txt" while accessing) and just try to access e.g site1.com/ads.txt site2.com/ads.txt.
- Another thing is you can create pages using page-ui, page-manager modules (for templates, html or php pages).
- Also you can write controller for the common page and in controller class just simply use the markup to render that page and add routing path for the same.